# double integrations on complex functions

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, numerical-integration

I am trying to perform a double integration of a function `MAG(qy,qz)` using the following line:

```py
results = np.trapz(np.trapz(MAG(qymap[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis],qzmap[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]), x=qzmap), x=qymap)
```

However the results of the integration returns a 2D arrays with "0" as value for each cells... How to perform correctly a double integration on qy and qz of the function `MAG(qy,qz)` ?

Here the complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as py
  
## Define the functions necessary
#%%
def theta(qy,qz):
    return np.arctan2(qy,qz)
 
##Define main function
#%%
def MAG(qy,qz):
    return np.cos(theta(qy,qz))


## Define qy and qz range and step
#%%
Ny = 50
Nz = 50

qy=np.linspace(-0.3,0.3,Ny)    ## define my qy values
qz=np.linspace(-0.3,0.3,Nz)    ## define my qz values


qymap=np.tile(qy,(Nz,1)).T
qzmap=np.tile(qz,(Ny,1))

#%%
##Perform the integration of the function MAG
results = np.trapz(np.trapz(MAG(qymap[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis],qzmap[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]), x=qzmap), x=qymap)
```

Comment: It's cool that you're posting code, and if you want to increase your chances of getting a meaningful reply, you can try and make it smaller (and still reproduces the issue). The best thing would be a few lines that is "essentially" the same. This way, experienced programmers can spot issues more easily.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it and reduced the code as much I can ;)

Comment: It can be simplified much more. Do you really need three different functions to reproduce the result? Certainly something simpler will do the job. Anyway, I'd look at [`dblquad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html).

Comment: right, only one is enough (updated)...thanks for the comments.

Comment: More can go! `R`, `H`, `qzL`, ...

Comment: You can show more effort. Much more can go.